# Android - How to get latitude and longitude values from outside OnMapReady function?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, google-maps-markers

I have this EventActivity where I have a map with a marker:

```
public class EventActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private GoogleMap eventMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);

        // Declares map fragment.
        SupportMapFragment eventMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.activity_event_map);
        eventMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        // Gets latitude and longitude values from database.

            // (things happen here and I get the values correctly)

            latitude = 12.4567785
            longitude = 25.7773665
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        eventMap = googleMap;

        // Sets map position.
        LatLng position = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        eventMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position));
        eventMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position));
    }

}
```

- On the **OnCreate()** I get the pair of double values **correctly**. I can even make a toast and it shows them.
- The problem is, when I want to set them as the position for the marker of my map on the **OnMapReady()** it gets nothing or **null**.

How can I properly pass the values from OnCreate() to OnMapReady()?

EDIT: I'm using Firebase as my database.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps initialize the map fragment after assigning the lat/long values as such:

```
public class EventActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   OnMapReadyCallback {

private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private GoogleMap eventMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);

    // Gets latitude and longitude values from database.

        // (things happen here and I get the values correctly)

        latitude = 12.4567785
        longitude = 25.7773665

    // Declares map fragment.
    SupportMapFragment eventMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.activity_event_map);
    eventMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    eventMap = googleMap;

    // Sets map position.
    LatLng position = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    eventMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position));
    eventMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position));
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks but still not working sir :( I would like to know if this is a normal behavior... I thought some sort of solution could be to edit the OnMapReady super method but I can´t do that neither... so here I am trapped out.

Comment: If you're using variables with a scope of the whole activity that are assigned in the onCreate they should already be accessible in onMapReady. Maybe also try removing the eventMap variable and just directly access the googleMap parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to solve a similar issue and currently have this solution working in my app.  I wanted to add a new polyline from my location to the marker in question so wanted setOnMarkerListener to have access to my location.  Here is how I solved it:

Step 1.
I created two global doubles as follows:

```
private Double myLatitude = -33.865143;
private Double myLongitude = 151.209900;
```

I gave them a default value of Sydney to avoid any NullPointerException error as I am adding polylines to an array of polylines.
 Step 2.
In my onLocationChanged method I updated the values:

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    myLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    myLongitude = location.getLongitude();
....
```

Now in Step 3 I wanted to create a new line from mylocation to the selected marker so used the following code:

```
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                areaText.setText(marker.getTitle());
                distanceText.setText("0 Meters");
                markerLatitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
                markerLongitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

                lines.add(mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude),
                                new LatLng(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude))
                        .width(10)
                        .color(Color.RED)));
                if (lines.size() > 1)
                    lines.remove((lines.size()-1));
                return true;
            }


        });
```

Hope this helps someone with the same issue.